# Export Azure Cosmos DB table to CSV

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-tables

I need to export the data that I have in Azure CosmosDB table to a CSV file.

I tried to use ADF but I only found configured for SQL and MongoDB and I am using TABLE STORAGE in COSMOSDB options .

Is there an easy or coded way to achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I found a way to export Azure data from CosmosDB table to a CSV file.

From what I found there is no way to export the data directly from the azure web portal but from [Azure Storage Explorer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/features/storage-explorer/) It is free and supported by Microsoft. Browse to the appropriate storage account, click on the table storage you want to export and look for the export option in the explorer.

I still have a code tool pending to solve this and make it more automatic

[image]

Comment: this is currently no longer allowed

Comment: Yea it sucks. Microsoft discontinued the CosmosDB support in Storage Explorer, and now the webUI is the only tool to access CosmosDB.

Answer (score 2):

I think I can share this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17010766) with you. Because I haven't found any docs to describe a solution to export data from cosmosdb table api.

First, it mentioned a [tool](https://www.cerebrata.com/products/cerulean/features/azure-cosmos-db/table-api) which is not free and provides download data as csv file.

[image]

And along the idea of writing code to achieve exporting data feature. I think it's also realizable for cosmosdb. You can query all the items you wanted and write them in csv file. Share a high voted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18757247) here and it recommend to use the library [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/), I think it's helpful to use `File.WriteAllText(filePath, csv.ToString());`

Comment: Do you have any other ideas on it?

Answer (score 2):

I [wrote a small library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Medienstudio.Azure.Data.Tables.CSV/) built on the new Azure.Data.Tables SDK to get Azure Storage Explorer compatible CSV exports.With that you can export to CSV file or to Azure BLOB Storage in a few lines of code and use it for example in Azure Storage. Note that it currently loads all data in memory though to create the proper CSV headers.

```cs
// Export all rows from the table to a CSV file
using StreamWriter writer = File.CreateText("test.csv");
await _tableClient.ExportCSVAsync(writer);

// Export all rows as CSV to Azure BLob Storage
BlobContainerClient containerClient = new(BlobConnectionString, "testcontainer");
var blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient("test.csv");
var stream = await blobClient.OpenWriteAsync(true, new BlobOpenWriteOptions() { HttpHeaders = new BlobHttpHeaders { ContentType = "text/csv" } });
using StreamWriter writer = new(stream);
await _tableClient.ExportCSVAsync(writer);
```